# how can i add classes to the content

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to add class to the content, however its not adding anything

```
    function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      $is_sidebar_first_or_second= (empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first'])) || (empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second']));
      $is_sidebar_first_and_second= (empty($vars['page']['sidebar_first'])) && (empty($vars['page']['sidebar_second']));
      if ($is_sidebar_first_or_second) {
        $vars['page']['content']['#theme_wrappers'][0] .= ' one-sidebar';
      }

      if ($is_sidebar_first_and_second) {
        $vars['page']['content']['#region'] .= ' two-sidebar';
      }

    }
```

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this code ?
I have taken it from [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

```
// Add information about the number of sidebars.
  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) && !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'two-sidebars';
  }
  elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'one-sidebar sidebar-first';
  }
  elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'one-sidebar sidebar-second';
  }
  else {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'no-sidebars';
  }
```

Comment: yes i got it and worked for me very nice

Comment: but if i want to add some classes to the blocks related to their region